# When I open the camera, I get a fatal error and the phone shuts down. This does not happen on iOS. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fatal-error, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-qrcode

I have a webview application and I use the following plugins for it.

```
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.0
  http: ^1.2.0
```

When I open the camera, I get a fatal error and the phone shuts down. This does not happen on iOS.

Fatal Error is:

```
F/flutter (10851): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/surface_texture_external_texture.cc(56)] Check failed: state_ == AttachmentState::kAttached. 

D/CameraPreview(10851): resume()
D/CameraInstance(10851): Opening camera
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(10851): Compat change id reported: 250678880; UID 10188; state: ENABLED
I/PlatformViewsController(10851): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 1
E/EGL_emulation(10851): eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/EGL_emulation(10851): tid 10851: eglQueryContext(2128): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
I/CameraBase(10851): Connect camera (legacy API) - overrideToPortrait 1, forceSlowJpegMode 0
D/CameraPreview(10851): resume()
W/CameraPreview(10851): initCamera called twice
E/FrameEvents(10851): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

Below are the pages where I got the error:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:yedek_parca/pages/scanner.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final Uri url;
  Home(this.url);
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          // useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
          cacheEnabled: true,
          supportZoom: false,
          clearCache: false),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(useHybridComposition: true),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
          allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true, sharedCookiesEnabled: true));

  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        child: Scaffold(
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
            body: SafeArea(
                child: InAppWebView(
                    key: webViewKey,
                    initialOptions: options,
                    pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
                    onWebViewCreated: (controller) =>
                        webViewController = controller,
                    onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                      print("Console: ${consoleMessage.message}");
                    },
                    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: widget.url),
                    onLoadStart: (_, url) async {
                      await askPermission(url);
                    }))),
        onWillPop: () async {
          bool canGoBack = (await webViewController?.canGoBack()) ?? false;
          if (canGoBack) {
            webViewController?.goBack();
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        });
  }

  Future<void> askPermission(Uri? url) async {
    var status = await Permission.camera.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      // Kamera izni iste
      await Permission.camera.request();
    }

    // Kullanıcının izin verip vermediğini kontrol et
    if (await Permission.camera.isGranted) {
      // Kamera erişimine izin verildi, burada istediğiniz işlemleri yapabilirsiniz.
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      if (url.toString() == "https://link") {
         Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  Scanner()));
      }
     
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
class Scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  // final Function(String value) onScanned;
  // const Scanner({super.key});
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _ScannerState createState() => _ScannerState();
}

class _ScannerState extends State<Scanner> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  bool canScan = true;
  bool isCameraInitialized = false;
  QRViewController? controller;
  final resultUrl =
      "https://link";
  final items = [
    NavigationModel(Icons.fullscreen, "TARA",
        Uri.parse("https://link")),
    NavigationModel(Icons.list, "PARÇA KODU",
        Uri.parse("https://link")),
    NavigationModel(Icons.list, "OEM KODU",
        Uri.parse("https://link")),
    NavigationModel(Icons.power_settings_new, "Geri",
        Uri.parse("https://link"))
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          label: const Text("Flaş"),
          onPressed: () => controller?.toggleFlash()),
      body: QRView(
          key: qrKey,
          onQRViewCreated: onQRViewCreated,
          overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
              borderColor: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: 30,
              borderLength: 60,
              borderWidth: 5)),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: items
              .map((x) =>
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(x.icon), label: x.title))
              .toList(),
          onTap: (index) {
            print(index);

            try {
              setState(() {
                if (index != 0) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Home(items[index].url)));
                }
              });
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  void onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    isCameraInitialized = true;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
      if (canScan) {
        if (scanData.code!.isNotEmpty) {
          canScan = false;
          final lst = await Requests.checkProduct(scanData.code!);
          if (lst.isEmpty) {
            showError();
          } else {
            this.controller?.dispose();
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    Home(Uri.parse(resultUrl + scanData.code!)),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void showError() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Hata"),
              content: Text("Ürün bulunamadı!"),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    child: Text("Tamam"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      canScan = true;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    })
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

please help me:(

When I open the camera for scan qr code, I get a fatal error and the phone shuts down. This does not happen on iOS. in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Flutter version 3.16.X, as there is an ongoing issue with that particular release [Flutter#138947](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138947)

If this is the case, you have two options:

**Option 1**

Downgrade Flutter to version 3.13.9:

```
flutter downgrade 3.13.9
```

**Option 2**

Switch to the Flutter master channel. However, please note that the master channel is not recommended for production apps:

```
flutter channel master
```

In the future, when reporting issues with Flutter, it is crucial to specify the Flutter version you are using.